# Catching key pressed with the virtual keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

With the physical keyboard you can catch key presses with a [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html), something like:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { 
            /* do something */ 
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how to do this (or similar) with the virtual keyboard?

Comment: Dont you think it would be a better idea to share the better way you found, i mean i come here asking for help, work out the answer your self and then dont give up the answer, more give and less take i think ;)

Answer (score 24):

So far i haven't found any listener for the virtual keypad in android. I found an alternate solution i.e. i used the TextChanged event to retrieve the value of the keys entered in the Edit Text.

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ShowKeypad extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.main); 
            EditText emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            emailTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {
                    public void  afterTextChanged (Editable s){ 
                            Log.d("seachScreen", "afterTextChanged"); 
                    } 
                    public void  beforeTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int 
                            count, int after)
                    { 
                            Log.d("seachScreen", "beforeTextChanged"); 
                    } 
                    public void  onTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int before, 
                            int count) 
                    { 
                            Log.d("seachScreen", s.toString()); 
                    }

            final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: If there is no entered text in editText? How do you think handle delete key?