# catch pressed key on the virtual keyboard (software keyboard) android

Tags: android

I need to catch a press of a key and return the keycode.
the key that was pressed on the **software** keyboard, I tried to find examples and explanations about that but they are a bit vague.

Does anyone know and can explain to me how to catch a keyboard key press?
(I understand onKeyListener is not good for me, and I found the onKeyActionListener but I still didn't understand how to use it, and if it really what I need)

Comment: You should provide examples of where it's vague to clarify what you're not understanding.

Comment: how to implement it, and how to work with the methods that I need to use there, I saw there is, for example the "onKey" method, but how do I call and use it?

Comment: Check the documents. Show more research effort.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html) helps.

Comment: actually, I'm looking to find a solution for days now..
I didnt find a lot about the actionListener..
Do you know about another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing you are looking for is

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {

                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER: //or any other key
                        //do something
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is exactly what not good for me..
the onKeyListener works only for hardware keyboard and I need for the software..

Comment: As far as I know it works for soft keyboard. It works in my applications.

Comment: @Keyser oh, i didn't know. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727605/645270) an answer to a similar question using a workaround.

You can also check out [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) for `TextView`'s.

A regular KeyListener works most of the time, but here's a quote from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html):

> Key presses on soft input methods are not required to trigger the
>   methods in this listener, and are in fact discouraged to do so. The
>   default android keyboard will not trigger these for any key to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only deliver it
>   for some key presses to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or
>   earlier.